# Error while upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 LTS packages from Local Repository

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-18.04, apt-get, apt

I am maintaining a local repository for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and recently updated the repository using apt-mirror. The I tried to upgrade the packages using the following commands

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The first two commands worked without any error. However, sudo apt-get upgrade resulted in the following error

```
Get:645 http://192.168.1.1/ubuntuRepo bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso all 5.2.18-1~ubuntu18.04.1 [39.0 MB]                                     
Err:645 http://192.168.1.1/ubuntuRepo bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso all 5.2.18-1~ubuntu18.04.1                                               
  File has unexpected size (38955904 != 39016736). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 192.168.1.1 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:f7c5ab5ea5b1feadc2cf5d8527d7c14c8b34439d5345fd04822f12381681b2a6
   - SHA1:5e0d43ebddd08d6256ac809c746de9c483ea83f1 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:b2e992fd6462e216bc651ddb020216b8 [weak]
   - Filesize:39016736 [weak]
Get:646 http://192.168.1.1/ubuntuRepo bionic-updates/main amd64 xbrlapi amd64 5.5-4ubuntu2.0.1 [61.9 kB]                                                                      
Fetched 763 MB in 1min 7s (11.4 MB/s)                                                                                                                                             
E: Failed to fetch http://192.168.1.1/ubuntuRepo/pool/multiverse/v/virtualbox-guest-additions-iso/virtualbox-guest-additions-iso_5.2.18-1~ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb  File has unexpected size (38955904 != 39016736). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 192.168.1.1 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - SHA256:f7c5ab5ea5b1feadc2cf5d8527d7c14c8b34439d5345fd04822f12381681b2a6
    - SHA1:5e0d43ebddd08d6256ac809c746de9c483ea83f1 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:b2e992fd6462e216bc651ddb020216b8 [weak]
    - Filesize:39016736 [weak]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

How to fix it?

The contents of my /etc/apt/sources.list is given below.

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.1.1/ubuntuRepo bionic main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.1.1/ubuntuRepo bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.1.1/ubuntuRepo bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.1.1/ubuntuRepo bionic-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.1.1/ubuntuRepo bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by clearing the files in /var/lib/apt/ and running sudo apt-mirror in my machine which holds the local repository.